# Use tensorflow's .ckpt model

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, embedding, triplestore

I used [this code](https://github.com/Lapis-Hong/TransE-Knowledge-Graph-Embedding) for training a model.
I now have 3 files:

- model.ckpt-1.meta
- model.ckpt-1.index
- model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001

How (with what methods) can I use these models now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with

> How (with what methods) can I use these models now?

The model is not saved in those files but i can be restored with them.

Those*.ckpt get saved during training but do not contain your model. If you want to "use" your model you need to restore those files to it. Take a look at Tensorflow's [Checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint) and [CheckpointManager](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointManager). This [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) shows a simple snipped of how to restore .ckpt files to your model.